# Bash script using Curl to output http status code fails with "could not resolve host"

Tags: bash, curl

I'm new to bash scripting and I keep getting "could not resolve host" when running the following script. I know it must be a slash or comma, but I have tried everything and can't figure it out. I've shortened the number of site for this example. Thanks in advance for any clues!

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 sites="https://www.example.com/comm/swift-lines/2012-advocate.html,
  4 "
  5 for site in ${sites//, }
  6 do
  7    #code='curl -I -L -k -s -o /dev/null -w  "%{http_code}" "http://${site}"'
  8    
  9    code=`curl -I -w "%{http_code}" "http://${site}"`
 10    echo "${site} ${code}"
 11 done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use arrays in bash too like in other languages and I think it's a better solution in this case. Using the `declare` keyword:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Declare the sites array:
declare -a sites=(
    "google.com"
    "stackoverflow.com"
)

# We loop every element in the sites array:
for site in "${sites[@]}"
do
    code=`curl -I -w "%{http_code}" "http://${site}"`
    echo "${site} ${code}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks! That's great to know! I found out my script contained "https://", which was causing the errors. When I ran your script I got the same error and that's what clued me in.